# Why does an Android Button() created in the java code have to use (this) as the context?

Tags: java, eclipse, button, android-studio

I can create a button in Eclipse using `Button button = new Button();`  (which comes from the `java.awt` import).  But how come in Android Studio, if I create a java code button using `Button button = new Button()` (which comes from the android.widget import), I get an error saying "cannot resolve constructor Button()" without using the `(this)` context?

Does this simply come down to a difference in how the Button() method is defined in the java.awt library and the android.widget library?

Comment: Please show some code: both the working and non-working code, in this case.

Comment: A `java.awt.Button` and a `android.widget.Button` are entirely different things.  You should not try to use AWT components or link the J2SE standard library into an Android app.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. That's what I was implying in my second paragraph in the. I confirmed this by checking the doc.  `java.awt.Button` reads as `public Button(){...}` whereas `android.widget.Button` reads as `public Button(Context context). Since this directly answers my question, I can mark it as an answer if you want to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button needs an Android Activity as its context so as it knows where to exist. "this" is referring to the activity which is creating the button. If you have multiple activities running, it would also be valid to pass one of the other activities in as the context.

Comment: the concept of a Context parameter is unique to Android correct?  I believe I read that context is something new that is used only with android java coding.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's unique to Android, but Android is the only place I've seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html), there is no constructor that takes no parameters. You must at least provide a `Context`.

Comment: when you say "there is no constructor that takes no parameters" are you referring specifically to Android?  Because in my original post, I cited how the java.awt.Button does not require a parameter or context.

Comment: @dbconfession : Just because they have the same name doesn't mean those classes are the same. You must always refer to the doc of the class you want to use if you bump into a problem. Look at the link I gave you.

Comment: @dbconfession : ok, so I was of course referring to  `android.widget.Button`.